Why is my variable resetting to zero everytime I am running the Macro
I have the following code.
Dim j As Long

Private Sub OK_Button_Click()
Dim x as string
if (Command for checking first time) then
j = 0
end if

'Code for x (not relevant to the question)

Call B(x, j)
j=j+1
End Sub

Normally, j should retain its value and keep adding 1 everytime I run the macro, but it is resetting to zero. What stupid error I am doing here?
(The code is part of a commond button on a userform. Dont know if that makes any difference)

Many possibilities (1) Your "Command for checking first time" is always executed. (2) You pass j by reference to B and the value is changed there (3) Other code changes the value (4) You create a new form object every time you show the form (for example because you use the infamous Unload). There is way too little information you provide to answer that question.

Apologies. I tried to simplify the code to put it up here and not provide any fluff.

It's okay that you simplified the code, but the piece you show doesn't contain enough information to help you. Does the form stays active when you press the OK button or is it closed and later reopened?


I can confirm that the first time code runs well.
The value is not changing in B
No other code
Indeed, the form has Unload Me at the end, which I hadnt included. Any workaround for it to not reset the value of j?


If you Unload the form, the complete form object is destroyed. Next time you show the form, a new form object is created (either bc you create it explicitly or by using the default instance). When a new object is created, of course the new form gets a new variable j that is initialized with 0. Easiest Workaround: Use Me.Hide instead of Me.Unload, with that the form object is not destroyed, only hidden. Dirty Workaround: Declare j as Global variable in a regular module.

Understand. Thank you for explaining. May I ask, why is declaring j as a global variable a dirty workaround?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

In VBA, variables declared with Dim within a module (but outside any procedure) have their scope limited to that module.
However, the problem here seems to be related to the initialization of j inside the OK_Button_Click subroutine. Specifically, if your "command for checking first time" is evaluating as true every time you click the button, it will reset j to zero.
Given that your j variable is declared at the module level and should retain its value between calls, the issue must be with the condition that resets j.   Ensure that the condition for checking the first time only evaluates to true the very first time the macro runs.
Here's an example of how you might modify your code to ensure j retains its value between button clicks:
Dim j As Long

Private Sub OK_Button_Click()
    Dim x As String
    
    ' Replace this condition with an appropriate check for the first-time run
    If j = 0 Then
        ' This block will only execute the very first time the button is clicked
        ' Make sure this logic correctly identifies the first run
        ' If you have other criteria to check for the first-time run, use that instead
        ' Example: If a specific cell is empty or a flag is not set
        ' If SomeCondition Then
        '     j = 0
        ' End If
    End If

    ' Code for x (not relevant to the question)

    Call B(x, j)
    j = j + 1
End Sub

In the example above, the condition If j = 0 Then ensures that j is only set to 0 if it hasn't been initialized yet, which should only be true on the first click if j hasn't been used or incremented before.
If your check for the first run is more complex (e.g., based on the state of the userform or other variables), make sure that it correctly identifies only the first run and doesn't reset j on subsequent clicks.
If you still encounter issues, consider adding a debug print statement to track the value of j and see how it changes with each click:
Dim j As Long

Private Sub OK_Button_Click()
    Dim x As String
    
    If j = 0 Then
        ' Initialization code here if needed
    End If

    ' Code for x (not relevant to the question)

    Call B(x, j)
    j = j + 1
    
    ' Debug print statement
    Debug.Print "Value of j: " & j
End Sub

By adding Debug.Print "Value of j: " & j, you can monitor the value of j in the Immediate Window in the VBA editor, which may help you understand how j is being modified.

I had indeed made a mistake while asking it . The module actually checks if it is the first time the macro runs and only then it sets j to 0, or else j is allowed to run as is. I have updated the question now. apologies.

I had added Msgbox j before and after j=j+1 command.
and it does show up as 0 and 1
But, i think the main concern lies in "Unload me" command that I didnt include in my original question.
